# Netty client, stops after connection to server

Tags: java, android, netty

I just started with `Netty`.

Currently I am trying to send an `Object` to a Server. I wrote some client in `Java`, and it's working fine. I also wrote an Android App that receives messages from a server. I tried to add some code for handling `Object`s to the Client part, but there is a problem.

It connects, but it's not sending messages. The Server is the same, so is the `Object`. Manifest is ok. I've tried multiple times to lunch `Java` client and `Android` client. Everything is working for `Java`. I am desperate already.

Here is my code

Client

```
public final class ObjectEchoClient {

    public static ChannelHandlerContext ctx;
    static final String HOST = System.getProperty("host", "192.168.0.101");
    static final int PORT = Integer.parseInt(System.getProperty("port", "8080"));


    public static void startClient() throws Exception {


        EventLoopGroup group = new NioEventLoopGroup();
        try {
            Bootstrap b = new Bootstrap();
            b.group(group)
             .channel(NioSocketChannel.class)
             .option(ChannelOption.SO_BACKLOG, 128)
             .option(ChannelOption.SO_KEEPALIVE, true) // (4)
             .handler(new ChannelInitializer<SocketChannel>() {
                @Override
                public void initChannel(SocketChannel ch) throws Exception {
                    ChannelPipeline p = ch.pipeline();

                    p.addLast(
                            new ObjectEncoder(),
                            new ObjectDecoder(ClassResolvers.cacheDisabled(null)),
                            new ObjectEchoClientHandler());
                }
             });

            // Start the connection attempt.
            b.connect(HOST, PORT).sync().channel().closeFuture().sync();


        } finally {
            group.shutdownGracefully();
        }
    }
}
```

Android MainActivity

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    public static UnixTime m;
    public static int id = 12345678;
    public static ChannelHandlerContext ctx;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        setRequestedOrientation (ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);

        socketTest();

        final Button btn1 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);


        btn1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                try {
                    //*
                    if(ObjectEchoClient.ctx != null)
                    { 
                        Package p = new Package();
                        p.setId(id);
                        ObjectEchoClient.ctx.writeAndFlush(p);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Log.e("test", "off");
                    }
                    //*/
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            }
        });

    }
public static void socketTest()
    {
        new Thread (new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    ObjectEchoClient.startClient();

                } catch (IOException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }   
            }}).start();

    }
```

P.S. If I add some message to the handler at the `channelActive` method in the `ObjectEchoClientHandler()`, it will be sent. but I need to send it when I will need to.

P.P.S Hendler

```
public class ObjectEchoClientHandler extends ChannelInboundHandlerAdapter {

    @Override
    public void channelActive(ChannelHandlerContext ctx) {

        ObjectEchoClient.ctx = ctx;

    }



    @Override
    public void channelRead(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, Object msg) {

    }

    @Override
    public void channelReadComplete(ChannelHandlerContext ctx) {
       ctx.flush();
    }

    @Override
    public void exceptionCaught(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, Throwable cause) {
        cause.printStackTrace();
        ctx.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: Your description is a bit confusing, and it would be good if you clarified what exactly the issue is. You mention that you were able to send (and receive on the other end) when you used the channel in the `channelActive` method.  Is this just a sequencing issue? You won't be able to use the channel unless it is active, and if events occur while the socket is not active you will have to queue events up until you have some active channel to use?

Comment: Yep, my question is basicly, why It's closing it immediatelly? I need it to wait. I believe this is the problem. Or I'am doing something wrong in 'MainActivity', when i'm trying to send a message, in the 'onClick'... I'am saving the 'ChannelHandlerContext', in the 'chanelActive', for the later use.

Comment: I'm not sure why "it's is closing immediately". That could depend on a bunch of things like is the peer closing the connection, environmental factors, and the rest of the code that isn't present here.  If you control both sides maybe run a tcpdump or some other network tool to see which side is initiating the close, and then dig in from there.

Comment: I figured out, that it's not closing. Some Netty codec is not working properly with android. Now i can send an Object if I will use `ObjectEchoClient.ctx.writeAndFlush(p+"/n");` But then Client is writing this `/n` to the stream, and on the Server i got `Package@3288446c/n`, So the package is a little bit corrupted. I still can try to insert my message to the `ByteBuf`, delete this `/n` from the ending, and try to cast it back to `Pakage`, but it looks like a pretty bad crutch for me. Is there any better solution?

Comment: And no, it's simply casting my `Object` to `String` before sending.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the problem was in the `writeAndFlush();` method. For Android it's not flushing properly data. So You need to flush it, once again.

```
ObjectEchoClient.ctx.writeAndFlush(p);
ctx.flush();
```

Answer (score 0):

I am a bit rusty here but when you call:

b.connect(HOST, PORT).sync().channel().closeFuture().sync();

are you not closing the channel as soon as it's opened ?

Sending a message on channel active is sending during the brief period the channel is connected, no ?

I'm still a netty3 diehard but looking at the 5 samples, to connect you want to:

ChannelFuture f = b.connect(HOST, PORT).sync();

And then later, to stop the client:

f.channel().closeFuture().sync();

Comment: No, `CloseFuture()` is just a future on the event "Close", so the command is waiting on future event close, before doing the gracefull shutdown. What I don't have is how the ctx is get for the onClick command, and if the ObjectEchoClientHandler is changed in anyway...?.

Comment: I've tried to add `Thread.sleep(1000);` in java client, before sending message. It is working fine, So I doubt that Server is disconecting Clients. And also i added the code of the handler to the first message here.